# How do I create a Windows-like clickable shortcut for Mac OSX?

Tags: java, macos, launch

I am helping a colleague set up some GUI programming tools I have written in Java.

I need to create a clickable icon to run the application which sets the current directory and then invokes the JVM, passing parameters to the program.  Also nice would be to be able to use the PNG icon image I created for the program.

I suspect I need to create a script and somehow add that to the launcher strip that's across the bottom of the screen.  Once off manual creation is all I need, not programmatic.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Use the **Jar Bundler**! With the Jar Bunder you can specify the Main class, any arguments, additional files and resources to the classpath, VM options and many more.

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac3/). There is also an [Ant task](http://jarbundler.sourceforge.net/) available (not tried myself yet). If you have installed [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html), it is located under `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Jar Bundler.app`. The Jar Bundler itself is not public downloadable (except the ant task). I'm not sure, if the Jar Bundler is part of the standard Mac OS distribution. Start the terminal and have a look at `/usr/share/java/Tools/Jar Bundler.app`. You need an apple developer account to get Xcode if it is not present.

Answer (score 1):

if you can do jnlp it will work in both mac and pc world

Comment: Ist'n a jnlp file for Java Web Start only?

Comment: @Arne Burmeister.  Sure JNLP is JWS based.  See the JWS Wiki (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  But since JWS is the way to go here, I do not understand your addition of 'only'.

Comment: This isn't a web-start application, it's an installed desktop app.

Comment: web-start application does get installed in desktop no? :) plus it will handle versioning, so if version is same it would run it, else it would prompt you to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

In OS X the closest thing to a shortcut that I am aware of is an alias. I'm not aware of any Java APIs for creating an alias directly, however you might consider invoking the `ln -s` command which creates a symbolic link, which is equivilant to an alias.

I can't confirm it works caus I'm on a PC but try

`ln -s "/path to/your/app -arg1 -arg2" "alias name"`

The OS X documentatiopn for the command is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ln.1.html)

Comment: We tried creating an alias, but could find no way to specify the current working directory with one.

Comment: An alias represents a soft link between two files. You might have to have the alias link to a script that sets the current working directory and then invokes the app. If memory serves you used to be able to set the icon for an alias in the Get Info dialog for an alias, that was PS 9, not sure it applies in OS X

Comment: The Mac generally doesn't care about the CWD. If your program requires knowledge of it, you may need to do some redesign.

Comment: My app does, and that's not likely to be redesigned since it's fairly fundamental.  So setting CWD is in effect critical to me at this juncture.

Comment: @robert: On OS X, an alias actually differs from a symbolic link. They serve a similar purpose, and the Finder displays them the same way, but they are different. (Specifically, an alias can deal with its target being moved. Also, Unix tools won't treat an alias as a symbolic link, as an alias is stored as a file in the file system.)